# Shared localization for asp.net, javascript and silverlight?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, silverlight, localization

How do you localize ASP.NET + javascript + Silverlight?

I would like to be able to include the same texts in different languages in asp.net pages, javascript on the page, and Silverlight objects on the page.

I have tried with the following method, but have no experience with it in practice, and I would like to hear your opinions on it or alternatives:

1) Create a class library (`ResourcesTest`) and add a resource file (`Phrases.resx`) with some strings (`Hello='Hello'`), plus a localized version (`Phrases.da.resx: Hello='Hej'`).

2) Add an empty javascript file (`PhrasesHandler.js`).

3) In AssemblyInfo.cs do this to allow the texts to be used by javascript/Silverlight:

```
[assembly: WebResource("ResourcesTest.PhrasesHandler.js", "application/x-javascript")]
[assembly: ScriptResource("ResourcesTest.PhrasesHandler.js", "ResourcesTest.Phrases", "Phrases")]
```

4) Reference the resource from ASP.NET code-behind (`ResourcesTest.Phrases.Hello`), or by including the embedded javascript resource in a web page:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="sm1" runat="server">
    <Scripts>
        <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="ResourcesTest" Name="ResourcesTest.PhrasesHandler.js" />
    </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

and then access the texts from javascript (e.g. `Phrases.Hello`), or from Silverlight via javascript (`HtmlPage.Window.Eval("Phrases.Hello")`).

I find this method rather complicated, and I worry about handling such a system, but have not found other ways of sharing localized/multi-language resources between ASP.NET, javascript and Silverlight.

Have you? How do you localize ASP.NET + javascript + Silverlight ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they can all accept data in JSON format, use that.

See: [Localize Strings in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104022/localize-strings-in-javascript)

Comment: Yes. I think JSON could do it for the client parts (Silverlight and javascript). Thanks for the suggestion.