# Localization of Confirm dialog box in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jquery dialog box to display Confirm & Cancel button as shown below:

```
  $("#delete_user").click(function(e) {
    $("#delete_user_dialog").dialog({
      buttons : {
        "Confirm" : function() {
          $(this).dialog("close");
          DeleteUser();
        },
        "Cancel" : function() {
          $(this).dialog("close");
        }
      }
    });
    $("#delete_user_dialog").dialog("open");
```

});

Is it possible to localize this text "Confirm" & "Cancel"??

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really it's just a matter of storing localized counterparts for each string: [Localize Strings in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104022/localize-strings-in-javascript/104157#104157).

And then detecting/having the user choose their language: [JavaScript for detecting browser language preference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043339/javascript-for-detecting-browser-language-preference)

When you create the dialog box, just choose the correct version of the string using the above. You will probably want to let the user opt-in to whatever language they want as opposed to automatically detecting their language every time. That way, multilingual users won't get upset.