# How to read a properties file with javascript

Tags: javascript, properties

I am trying to display a web page according to the language that I will specified. For example:

```
<body>
  <div id="monlabel"> Bonjour </div>
</body>
```

when I choose frensh, the text in the div text will be 'bonjour', and when I choose english, the div text will be 'good morning'.
I thought about a properties file, but I didn't figure out how to read it using the javascript and apply it to my web page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Related: [How should I go about localising an existing JavaScript web application?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8062303/464709)

Comment: Thanks for the links, but did you have any other solutions because I didn't found a clear example about how to change the div value! I hope that you have understand my problem ;)