# Compile resx to Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, msbuild, resx

Is there a way to compile resx file to Javascript during build time? I found only this: [Localize Strings in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104022/localize-strings-in-javascript) which is useless in my case because I have really many strings to put in javascript.

Comment: Because I will need generator to output 200 properties.

Answer (score 2):

I think some of the answers in your link would allow for muliple properties.

But there are other solutions:
http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Apr/02/A-Localization-Handler-to-serve-ASPNET-Resources-to-JavaScript

If you search for "convert resx json" you will find different approaches.

Comment: It is cool, but if I can do this during compilation time I can bundle this script. Anyway +1 I will explore this solution

Comment: There are tons of similar solutions out there. We explored it too for while, but now just serialize all page resources into a json object and dump it onto the page.